# Filling / Transforming polygon correctly in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I have following polygon marked:

[image]

I need to fill the inside of the polygon correctly.

Using following code:

```
using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Yellow)))
{
   e.Graphics.FillPolygon(br, points);
}
```

Where `points` is `System.Drawing.Point[] points = new System.Drawing.Point[total_points_size];`

Above `points` array will contain multiple Point(s) with there X,Y respectively. You can see the blue ellipsis in image.

Following are the co-ordinates:

[image]

I get following result:

[image]

I just need the polygon to be filled from inside, looks like due to some reason the markup is going to (0,0) for each point, how can we fix this ?

I have learned the solution might involve graphics transform with offset, but I'm not able to figure out exact solution.

Comment: Try to dump the point array.

Comment: @MarioVernari , no they don't match. Is this the only issue ? . Let me quickly try the fix.

Comment: I removed my previous comment, because I actually was unsure about it. Try to dump the array, then we'll see.

Comment: First, determine whether the pixel point is inside the polygon or not. If there is, put the average of  'N' surrounding points. The image is blurred

Comment: @MarioVernari updated the question with co-ordinates

Comment: @MarioVernari any update on this buddy ? Still haven't figured out.

Comment: @Vikrant I just tried. I made a NET 7 Winforms app and I used your code and points. It works fine: no strange behavior. The polygon shows as expected. Are you sure there's no something else drawing on the canvas with the same array of points? my suspect is on that, at this point

Comment: @MarioVernari - I am using .NET 4.7.2 , considering that might be an only difference. I will try to a make simple new project to test this case. I do not see any other things which can impact.

Comment: @Vikrant You can try to replace the lower version of .net framework.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT lowering the .net framework version didnt fix the issue.

Comment: @Vikrant Hello, is it convenient for you to provide a github address with your project? Your issue is hard to reproduce with the information you provided.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT yes, Winforms comes with NET7 also. Have a read here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/winforms-enhancements-in-dotnet-7/

Comment: @Vikrant just tried with NET4.7.2 and it works fine, as the NET7 one. I'd post your code somewhere in order to better analyze it. I don't think the problem is in the snippet above.

Comment: @MarioVernari can you please upload your project with .Net4.7.2 ? I would really consider studying it. As there is nothing complex going on here.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT @Mario Vernari , I was able to figure out the issue. Actually it was a basic silly mistake in my code. The issue was , I was filling the polygon `e.Graphics.FillPolygon(br,p)` inside the `for loop` where I was filling up the `points array`. There was lot going on above filling the polygon and misjudged the end brackets. I am going to accept the answer provided by Mario Vernari and close this question, it gives a straightforward idea about the implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the supposedly equivalent code to plot your polygon. I tested it with both Net7 and NET 4.7.2.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
    }

    private static readonly Point[] points = new[]
    {
        new Point(62, 478),
        new Point(333, 411),
        new Point(411, 392),
        new Point(650, 454),
        new Point(784, 467),
        new Point(1105, 529),
        new Point(1136, 574),
        new Point(1182, 580),
        new Point(1247, 689),
        new Point(24, 693),
    };

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
        using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Yellow)))
        {
            g.FillPolygon(br, points);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the graphic result.
[image]

Comment: I am using graphics variable `e.Graphics.FillPolygon` which is created from `PaintEventArgs`. I can see you are creating the graphics variable from `Graphics g= this.CreateGraphics()`, Or is it the same thing ?

Comment: Yes, they are the same, just in a different way. But because your issue is relatively rare, I suggest you try again according to Mario Vernari‘s method to see if it works.